# Good practice on how to store the result of a function for later use in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have the situation where I have written an R function, `ComplexResult`, that computes a computationally expensive result that two other separate functions will later use, `LaterFuncA` and `LaterFuncB`.

I want to store the result of `ComplexResult` somewhere so that both `LaterFuncA` and `LaterFuncB` can use it, and it does not need to be recalculated. The result of `ComplexResult` is a large matrix that only needs to be calculated once, then re-used later on.

R is my first foray into the world of functional programming, so interested to understand what it considered good practice. My first line of thinking is as follows:

```
# run ComplexResult and get the result
cmplx.res <- ComplexResult(arg1, arg2)

# store the result in the global environment. 
# NB this would not be run from a function 
assign("CachedComplexResult", cmplx.res, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Is this at all the right thing to do? The only other approach I can think of is having a large "wrapper" function, e.g.:

```
MyWrapperFunction <- function(arg1, arg2) {
    cmplx.res <- ComplexResult(arg1, arg2)

    res.a <- LaterFuncA(cmplx.res)
    res.b <- LaterFuncB(cmplx.res)

    # do more stuff here ...
}
```

Thoughts? Am I heading at all in the right direction with either of the above? Or is an there Option C which is more cunning? :)

Comment: with `cmplx.res <- ComplexResult(arg1, arg2)` you are doing a assignation so you don't need to do it 2 times. In my practice the best way to store a large tables/matrix is in a ".txt" file. `write.table` and `read.table` work very fast

Comment: `save(object,file="filename")` if you want to use the object again `load(file="filename")`

Answer (score 3):

The general answer is you should Serialize/deSerialize your big object for further use. The R way to do this is using `saveRDS/readRDS`:

```
## save a single object to file
saveRDS(cmplx.res, "cmplx.res.rds")
## restore it under a different name
cmplx2.res <- readRDS("cmplx.res.rds")
```

Comment: and use memoise in addition of physical cache.

Answer (score 1):

This assign to GlobalEnv:

```
CachedComplexResult <- ComplexResult(arg1, arg2)
```

To store I would use:

```
write.table(CachedComplexResult, file = "complex_res.txt")
```

And then to use it directly:

```
LaterFuncA(read.table("complex_res.txt"))
```

Comment: The local assignment operator [`<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) will assign to the enclosing environment. If this happens to be in global scope, then it will indeed assign to [`.GlobalEnv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html), however, if it takes place inside a function, then it will assign to the evaluation environment of the function call.

Comment: The superassignment operator `<<-` will always assign to the global environment, provided that there is no closure variable of that name in an intervening parent environment. However, R experts often recommend against using it as bad practice, although I have found uses for it on occasion.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I suppose in this case he was doing the same operation 2 times: with `<-` operator and with `assign` function. And if you want to assign to global inside a function I agree that it is better with `assign` function rather then `<<-` operator

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works for saving to local memory; other answers have explained saving to global memory or a file. Here are some thoughts on *why* you would do one or the other.

Save to file: this is slowest, so only do it if your process is volatile and you expect it to crash hard and you need to pick up the pieces where it left off, OR if you just need to save the state once in a while where speed/performance is not a concern.

Save to global: if you need access from multiple spots in a large R program.